# Install uno platform on Windows 10

Tags: uno-platform

I have installed Visual studio 2017 15.5 but i cannot install uno platform extension. it always saying that some prerequisites cannot be resolved.

Comment: Do you have Xamarin installed?

Comment: Wondering about xamarin also. But anything other prerequisite from here could be missing ? https://github.com/nventive/Uno.QuickStart

Comment: In the view logs, it tell that Microsoft.visualStuio.Component.CoreEditor missing

Answer (score 2):

In the VisualStudio Installer, you need those *workloads*:

1. UWP development
2. Mobile Development with .NET
3. .NET Core cross-platform development *(maybe this one is missing!)*